# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (alert connected)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, alert

what is the error in this statement

```
<?php

session_start();

$host = "localhost";
$uname = "root";
$pass = "";
$database = "mcndb";
$cons = mysqli_connect($host, $uname, $pass, $database);
mysqli_select_db($cons, $database);


if (!$cons) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
    $today = date("Y/m/d  h:i:s:A");
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($cons, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($cons, $_POST['password']);
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($cons, $_POST['firstname']);
    $middlename = mysqli_real_escape_string($cons, $_POST['middlename']);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($cons, $_POST['lastname']);
    //  $age=mysqli_real_escape_string($cons,$_POST['age']);
    $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($cons, $_POST['gender']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($cons, $_POST['usremail']);
    $companyname = mysqli_real_escape_string($cons, $_POST['companyname']);
    $position = mysqli_real_escape_string($cons, $_POST['position']);

    $contactnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($cons, $_POST['contactnumber']);
    $addresss = mysqli_real_escape_string($cons, $_POST['address']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbltry (username,password,email,firstname,middlename,lastname,gender, company_name,position,contact_number,address_of_company,dateofregister) 
            VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email','$firstname', '$middlename','$lastname','$gender', '$companyname','$position','$contactnumber','$addresss','$today')";


    if ($cons->query($sql) == TRUE) {
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'alert("Successfully created an account")';
        echo '</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script>';
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $cons->error;
        echo 'alert("Account already exist")';
        echo '</script>';

    }

}
?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv9Xh.jpg)

the problem with this is that when ever i try registering a dulicate value to unique column in databse, the error message in the alert dont show up and it does not show any kind of error even in sql it just says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier so what is wrong with my code that the alert for error dont show?

Comment: Please show the parsed code instead of that PHP mess.

Comment: Why are you entering HTML inside a script tag?

Comment: I just copy that script tag from w3schools sql insert into tutorial

Comment: @ErzaScarlet: Well, that was your first mistake.  W3Schools is a *terrible* resource for learning PHP.  What they're teaching you is downright wrong, and has been for many years.  Though I doubt even *they* would make the error you've made here (answered below).

Comment: not its okay @David thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so what is wrong with my code

This:

```
<script>
  Error: some text<br>some more text
  alert("Account already exist")
</script>
```

(And potentially other things, but this seems to be where the error you're currently seeing takes place.)

That first line of JavaScript code isn't actually JavaScript code.  It's just text.  So `Error:` (and everything after it) is an unexpected identifier as far as JavaScript is concerned.

I suspect you meant to put that text outside of the script block:

```
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $cons->error;
echo '<script>';
echo 'alert("Account already exist")';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: that script purpose is to show if my insert into statement is correct or not, and alert to show the message. my problem is that when i try registering a new acc it is successful and alert shows the proof but when i try registering acc with same username as one in the database the alert for error for dulicate insert do not show and the page just refresh. What should i do?

Comment: @ErzaScarlet: Well, I guess you'd have to do a little debugging in that case.  Examine what is actually returned by the server, include some test output in your script to see which code blocks (ifs and elses, for example) are being executed, etc.  Unless another error is stopping execution, *one* of those two blocks (if or else) is going to be executed, that's simply how `if` conditions work.

Comment: Yeah hope i got it in time, i just get that script tag from w3schools sql insert inti tutorial and make some adjustment, the alert in succes is ok but the hell alert in else is not :(

Comment: Can you make me a scrip tag or any code to make sure if that insert into statement is success or not pls

Comment: @ErzaScarlet: No, nobody here is going to write all of your code for you.  This answer already corrects the problem you were having.  It's not clear what other problems may be happening, but you can feel free to update the question or, if it's an entirely new problem, ask a new question.  At the moment it's not really clear what additional help you need.  You would need to provide your updated code as well as an updated description of the problem.